# Python code that adds a new value to the list when it finds the elements of one list in another list

Tags: python, list, search

```
L1 =['0-0-3-0-0-80-0', '0-0-3-0-0-82-0']

L2 = [['0', '4', '0', '0', '42', '71','42','0-0-0-0-0-4-0'],['0', '4', '2', '0', '42', '72','42', '0-0-0-1-0-4-2'],['0', '80', '0', '0', '42', '81','43', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0'],['0', '80', '0', '1', '21', '81','43', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0'],['0', '81', '0', '0', '43', '82', '21', '0-0-3-1-0-81-0',],['0', '82', '0', '0', '21', '83', '43', '0-0-3-0-0-82-0']]
```

So I want to search L1's values in L2 lists if code finds the value

```
'0-0-3-0-0-80-0' is in ['0', '80', '0', '0', '42', '81','43', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0'] and ['0', '80', '0', '1', '21', '81','43', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0']

and

'0-0-3-0-0-82-0' is in ['0', '82', '0', '0', '21', '83', '43', '0-0-3-0-0-82-0']
```

Last result will be shown as like that

```
L2 = [['0', '4', '0', '0', '42', '71','42','0-0-0-0-0-4-0',""],['0', '4', '2', '0', '42', '72','42', '0-0-0-1-0-4-2',""],['0', '80', '0', '0', '42', '81','43', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0',"found"],['0', '80', '0', '1', '21', '81','43', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0',"found"],['0', '81', '0', '0', '43', '82', '21', '0-0-3-1-0-81-0',],['0', '82', '0', '0', '21', '83', '43', '0-0-3-0-0-82-0',"found"]]

for i in range(0,len(L2)):
    for x in L1:
        if x in L2[i]:
           result.append(L2[i]+["found"])
       else:
           result.append(L2[i]+[""])
```

I tried this but it duplicates results two times.

The code creates results for two times.

Comment: What is the duplication that you refer to?

Comment: my code writes two times for all elements of L1

Comment: I'm not sure I see that when I run your code. What specifically are you seeing?

Comment: I think the `duplicate` you are referring to comes from the fact that `len(L1) == 2`. You should try: `L1 =['0-0-3-0-0-80-0', '0-0-3-0-0-82-0', 'foo']` and you will see triplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to append `"found"` or `""` to each list in `L2`.

The code below appends `""` by default and overwrites it with `"found"` each time something is found.  There is no `result` variable needed:

```py
for i in range(0,len(L2)):
    if len(L2[i]) == 8:
        L2[i].append('')
    for x in L1:
        if x in L2[i]:
            L2[i][8] = 'found'
```

Output as requested